# Echo after dropdown seletion in php

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I'm new in PHP, so I need some help. I have XML file containing information's about Song name, Author name and ID. I use this XML file to import song names into drop down menu.

After visitor selects song name from drop down menu, he should get author name, but I don't know how to create this.

Here is my xml file:

```
<songs>
<song>
    <name>I left my heart on Europa</name>
<author>Author name 1</author>
    <id>1</id>
</song>
<song>
    <name>Oh Ganymede</name>
<author>Author name 2</author>
    <id>2</id>
</song>
<song>
    <name>Kallichore</name>
<author>Author name 3</author>
    <id>3</id>
</song>
```

and my php file:

```
<?php
$songs = simplexml_load_file('rss.xml');
echo "<select id='SELsongs'>";
foreach($songs as $song)
{
echo "<option value='".$song->id."'>".$song->name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Best regards,
Milan

Comment: Remember, PHP is serverside, it handles on request. So you need to do a request. This can be a normal `HTTP request` like you are used to, or something like an `asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request`. I think you could use jQuery's AJAX functionality http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Chained SELECT Boxes using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970315/dynamic-chained-select-boxes-using-jquery) amongst MANY other examples of what you want.